# Example a bounded function on $[0,1]$ such that Continuous at $(0,1]$ and but at $x=0$ Discontinuous.

Tags: calculus

> Example a bounded function on $[0,1]$ such that continuous at $(0,1]$ and but at $x=0$ Discontinuous.

---

My example :
$$f(x)=\sin x  \ \  \ : \ \ \ $$

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\sin x,  & 0< x<\frac{\pi}{2} \\[2ex]
3 & x=0
\end{cases}$$

it is right ?

Comment: Well, you need to adjust the domain so that the first piece function is defined on $(0,1]$. Note, $\sin(x)$ is nothing special. You could have used $x$ instead, or, for that matter, a constant function (e.g., the zero function).

Comment: well, the domain of your function is $[0,\pi/2]$ not $[0,1]$ but otherwise, yes, this will work

Comment: [Indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) on $(0,1]$.

Comment: If you have any continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$ (in particular $f$ is bounded) then defining $g(x) = f(x)$ for $x \in (0,1]$ and $g(0) = a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{f(x)\}$ will give you an example.

Answer (score 1):

no, but the problem is the upper bound and not the lower, if $f(x)\in[0,1]$ you cant say $f(x)=\sin x$ when $0<x<\frac\pi 2$, you need to say $f(x)=\sin x$ when $0<x\le1$.

note that using $\sin x$ is good not because $\sin x$ is a special function but because it is continuous over $(0,1]$, you could use $\cos x, x, x^4, e^x, etc.$ as long it is continuous and the value when $x=0$ isnt the same as the value when the function when $x\ne0$ is equal to $0$. for example for if you chose $3x+3$ when $0<x\le1$ you cant choose $3$ for $x=0$